# Tree structure, display text of clicked elements from structure

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

This is my code for tree structure. When i click on Tag 1 gets class="active", when i click on Asia gets class="open", when i click on Southern-West gets class="open" and when i click on India gets class="selected". Everything is shown in picture on link: http://postimg.org/image/4216vmlpj/

```
<div class="container responsive-tabs-default">
        <ul class="responsive-tabs">
            <li><a href="#example-1-tab-1" target="_self">Tag 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#example-1-tab-2" target="_self">Tag 2 </a></li>   
        </ul>

        <div class="responsive-tabs-content bm-larger">
            <div id="example-1-tab-1" class="responsive-tabs-panel">

                    <!-- TREE BEGIN-->

                    <h1>Naslov</h1>
                        <!--  <input type="search" id="my-search" placeholder="search"> -->
                        <ul id="my-tree1">
                            <li>
                                <div>Asia</div>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <div>Southern-West</div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><div>India</div></li>
                                            <li><div>Pakistan</div></li>
                                            <li><div>Butan</div></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><div>Southern-East</div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><div>Indonesia</div></li>
                                            <li><div >Vietnam</div></li>
                                            <li><div >malaysia</div></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><div>Far-east</div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><div>China</div></li>
                                            <li><div>North Korea</div></li>
                                            <li><div>South Korea</div></li>
                                            <li><div>Japan</div></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><div>Central</div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><div>Mongol</div></li>
                                            <li><div>kazakhstan</div></li>
                                            <li><div>kyrgyzstan</div></li>
                                        </ul>                       
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><div>Antarctica</div></li>
                            <li>
                                <div>Africa</div>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><div>Moroco</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Egypt</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Ghana</div></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div>Europe</div>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><div>United Kingdom</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Sweden</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Germany</div></li>
                                    <li><div>France</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Spain</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Italy</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Austria</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Turkey</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Russia</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Denmark</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Finland</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Iceland</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Switzerland</div></li>
                                    <li><div>Hungary</div></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul> 
                    <!-- TREE END-->
            </div>
            <div id="example-1-tab-2" class="responsive-tabs-panel">

                <h1>Naslov</h1>
                    <!--  <input type="search" id="my-search" placeholder="search"> -->
                    <ul id="my-tree2">
                        <li>
                            <div>Asia</div>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <div>Southern-West</div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><div>India</div></li>
                                        <li><div>Pakistan</div></li>
                                        <li><div>Butan</div></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><div>Southern-East</div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><div>Indonesia</div></li>
                                        <li><div>Vietnam</div></li>
                                        <li><div>malaysia</div></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><div>Far-east</div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><div>China</div></li>
                                        <li><div>North Korea</div></li>
                                        <li><div>South Korea</div></li>
                                        <li><div>Japan</div></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><div>Central</div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><div>Mongol</div></li>
                                        <li><div>kazakhstan</div></li>
                                        <li><div>kyrgyzstan</div></li>
                                    </ul>                       
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><div>Antarctica</div></li>
                        <li>
                            <div>Africa</div>
                            <ul>
                                <li><div>Moroco</div></li>
                                <li><div>Egypt</div></li>
                                <li><div>Ghana</div></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div>Europe</div>
                            <ul>
                                <li><div>United Kingdom</div></li>
                                <li><div>Sweden</div></li>
                                <li><div>Germany</div></li>
                                <li><div>France</div></li>
                                <li><div>Spain</div></li>
                                <li><div>Italy</div></li>
                                <li><div>Austria</div></li>
                                <li><div>Turkey</div></li>
                                <li><div>Russia</div></li>
                                <li><div>Denmark</div></li>
                                <li><div>Finland</div></li>
                                <li><div>Iceland</div></li>
                                <li><div>Switzerland</div></li>
                                <li><div>Hungary</div></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul> 
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'd like that text is shown in the right side of page, like it's shown on picture. So when i clic on Tag 1, ther is written Tag 1. When i click on Asia, there is written Asia... like on the picture. I found a sollution that shows me the clicked text, but not working fine. When i click on Asia, not only Asia is written, but there is written Asia Southern-West India Pakistan Butan Southern-East Indonesia Vietnam ...so all elements of tree structure below Asia are shown when i click on Asia, but only Asia must be shown. And second isue is, that not all my selections are written. So if i select Tag 1 and Antarctica, there will be Tag 1 and Antarctica shown, when i click on Tag 2, Tag 1 is replaced by Tag 2. I'd like that previous selection is stored and shown and when i make a new selection it's written below the first selection. That also must work with countries. When i choose Tag 1 Antarctika, and then Europe - Spain must both selections be displayed, so Tag 1 Antarctica and Tag 1 Europe Spain.

There is a code that i figured out so far:

```
<script>
                         $("").click(function () {
                        <!--    $(this).addClass('tf-selected');
                              var str = "";
                               $("li.active").each(function () {
                                   str +=  $(this).text() +" ";
                               });
                                $(".display_text_here").text(str);
                        });
                    </script>

                    <script>
                         $("").click(function () {
                        <!--    $(this).addClass('tf-selected');
                              var str = "";
                               $("li.tf-open").each(function () {
                                   str +=  $(this).text() +" ";
                               });
                                $(".display_text_here2").text(str);
                        });
                    </script>

                    <script>
                         $("").click(function () {
                        <!--    $(this).addClass('tf-selected');
                              var str = "";
                               $("li.tf-selected").each(function () {
                                   str +=  $(this).text() +" ";
                               });
                                $(".display_text_here3").text(str);
                        });
                    </script>
                    <div class="display_text_here"></div> 
                    <div class="display_text_here2"></div> 
                    <div class="display_text_here3"></div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Responsive Tabs v1.4, Copyright 2014, Joe Mottershaw, https://github.com/joemottershaw/ -->
<html lang="en" class="no-js">

<head>

  
 <!-- tree  begin--> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi">

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="tree/jquery.treefilter.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=roboto:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  
  <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- display selected -->
  
  <style>
   body  {background:#fff; padding:0;}
   .container {font-family:"roboto"; font-size:16px; background:#fff; border-radius:3px;
      border:1px solid #ddd;}
   h1   {color:#08f; font-weight:100; font-size:44px; margin-top:150px;}
   input  {background:transparent; font-size:16px; border:1px solid #ddd; border-width:0 0 1px 0; border-radius: 0; line-height:40px; height:40px; width:100%; outline:none;}
   ul#my-tree {margin:0; padding:10px 5px; color:#666;}
   ul#my-tree li{margin:8px 0;}
   div.desc {margin:20px 0; color:#aaa; font-size:11px; text-align:left;}
  </style>

  <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="tabs/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <link href="tabs/css/responsive-tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
  <link href="tabs/css/style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

</head>

<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<table style="width:100%">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2" style="background: transparent url('images/top-ozadje2.bmp') repeat-x;">
 
 <!-- Header -->
   <h1 style="padding-left:45%"> SELECTION </h1> 
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td valign="top">
 <!-- Content -->
  <div class="container responsive-tabs-default">
   <ul class="responsive-tabs">
    <li><a href="#example-1-tab-1" target="_self">Tag 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#example-1-tab-2" target="_self">Tag 2 </a></li> 
   </ul>

   <div class="responsive-tabs-content bm-larger">
    <div id="example-1-tab-1" class="responsive-tabs-panel">
   
      <!-- TREE BEGIN-->
      
      <h1>Naslov</h1>
       <!--  <input type="search" id="my-search" placeholder="search"> -->
       <ul id="my-tree1">
        <li>
         <div>Asia</div>
         <ul>
          <li>
           <div>Southern-West</div>
           <ul>
            <li><div>India</div></li>
            <li><div>Pakistan</div></li>
            <li><div>Butan</div></li>
           </ul>
          </li>
          <li><div>Southern-East</div>
           <ul>
            <li><div>Indonesia</div></li>
            <li><div >Vietnam</div></li>
            <li><div >malaysia</div></li>
           </ul>
          </li>
          <li><div>Far-east</div>
           <ul>
            <li><div>China</div></li>
            <li><div>North Korea</div></li>
            <li><div>South Korea</div></li>
            <li><div>Japan</div></li>
           </ul>
          </li>
          <li><div>Central</div>
           <ul>
            <li><div>Mongol</div></li>
            <li><div>kazakhstan</div></li>
            <li><div>kyrgyzstan</div></li>
           </ul>      
          </li>
         </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div>Antarctica</div></li>
        <li>
         <div>Africa</div>
         <ul>
          <li><div>Moroco</div></li>
          <li><div>Egypt</div></li>
          <li><div>Ghana</div></li>
         </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div>Europe</div>
         <ul>
          <li><div>United Kingdom</div></li>
          <li><div>Sweden</div></li>
          <li><div>Germany</div></li>
          <li><div>France</div></li>
          <li><div>Spain</div></li>
          <li><div>Italy</div></li>
          <li><div>Austria</div></li>
          <li><div>Turkey</div></li>
          <li><div>Russia</div></li>
          <li><div>Denmark</div></li>
          <li><div>Finland</div></li>
          <li><div>Iceland</div></li>
          <li><div>Switzerland</div></li>
          <li><div>Hungary</div></li>
         </ul>
        </li>
       </ul> 
      <!-- TREE END-->
    </div>
    <div id="example-1-tab-2" class="responsive-tabs-panel">
     
     <h1>Naslov</h1>
      <!--  <input type="search" id="my-search" placeholder="search"> -->
      <ul id="my-tree2">
       <li>
        <div>Asia</div>
        <ul>
         <li>
          <div>Southern-West</div>
          <ul>
           <li><div>India</div></li>
           <li><div>Pakistan</div></li>
           <li><div>Butan</div></li>
          </ul>
         </li>
         <li><div>Southern-East</div>
          <ul>
           <li><div>Indonesia</div></li>
           <li><div>Vietnam</div></li>
           <li><div>malaysia</div></li>
          </ul>
         </li>
         <li><div>Far-east</div>
          <ul>
           <li><div>China</div></li>
           <li><div>North Korea</div></li>
           <li><div>South Korea</div></li>
           <li><div>Japan</div></li>
          </ul>
         </li>
         <li><div>Central</div>
          <ul>
           <li><div>Mongol</div></li>
           <li><div>kazakhstan</div></li>
           <li><div>kyrgyzstan</div></li>
          </ul>      
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><div>Antarctica</div></li>
       <li>
        <div>Africa</div>
        <ul>
         <li><div>Moroco</div></li>
         <li><div>Egypt</div></li>
         <li><div>Ghana</div></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div>Europe</div>
        <ul>
         <li><div>United Kingdom</div></li>
         <li><div>Sweden</div></li>
         <li><div>Germany</div></li>
         <li><div>France</div></li>
         <li><div>Spain</div></li>
         <li><div>Italy</div></li>
         <li><div>Austria</div></li>
         <li><div>Turkey</div></li>
         <li><div>Russia</div></li>
         <li><div>Denmark</div></li>
         <li><div>Finland</div></li>
         <li><div>Iceland</div></li>
         <li><div>Switzerland</div></li>
         <li><div>Hungary</div></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       
      </ul> 
    </div>    
   </div>
  </div>
  </td>
  <td valign="top">  
   <div class="container2" > 
    <ul class="responsive-tabs">
     <h3>You have choosen:</h3>
     <button type="button" onClick="window.location.reload()">Delete choosen data</button>
     <hr> 
    </ul> 
    <p> 
           
      <script>
        $("").click(function () {
       <!-- $(this).addClass('tf-selected');
          var str = "";
           $("li.active").each(function () {
            str +=  $(this).text() +" ";
           });
         $(".display_text_here").text(str);
       });
      </script>
      
      <script>
        $("").click(function () {
       <!-- $(this).addClass('tf-selected');
          var str = "";
           $("li.tf-open").each(function () {
            str +=  $(this).text() +" ";
           });
         $(".display_text_here2").text(str);
       });
      </script>
      
      <script>
        $("").click(function () {
       <!-- $(this).addClass('tf-selected');
          var str = "";
           $("li.tf-selected").each(function () {
            str +=  $(this).text() +" ";
           });
         $(".display_text_here3").text(str);
       });
      </script>
      <div class="display_text_here"></div> 
      <div class="display_text_here2"></div> 
      <div class="display_text_here3"></div> 
    </p>  
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
 
 <!-- Footer --> 
   
 <!-- JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="tabs/js/smoothscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="tabs/js/backbone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="tabs/js/responsive-tabs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
 <!-- tree begin -->
 
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="tree/jquery.treefilter.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
   var tree = new treefilter($("#my-tree1"), {
    searcher : $("input#my-search"),
    multiselect : false });
  });
  </script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
   var tree = new treefilter($("#my-tree2"), {
    searcher : $("input#my-search"),
    multiselect : false });
  });
  </script>
  
  <script>
  $(function() {
   var tree = new treefilter($("#my-tree3"), {
    searcher : $("input#my-search"),
    multiselect : false });
  });
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
  
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
   var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
   ga.tree = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

  </script>
  
 <!-- tree end -->
</table> 
</body>

</html>
```

Snipped cant work fine cause there is manj js and css scripts behind my page.

Can anyone make a suggestion how to improve my sollution that will work on my expectacion.

Thanks all for help

P.S.
Below answer is great. Thank you very much for all the effort. I have one more question. When i reload (or first open) a page, one of the tabs is already chossen (opened) and tree structure of that tab is shown. What should i change that this automaticly choosen tab is also automaticly written in right side if i choose one of the countries from tree structure? Because if i choose one of the countries from automaticly open Tag, name of this tag isn't written in front of country name.

And one more, when i choose Africa - Maroco then Europe - Germany it's working great. But if i make one more selection from Africa, like Egypt, this one is written belov Germany (I get Europe - Germany - Egypt). What should i change that in this case Egypt in written below Maroco from previous selection, not bellow Germany from the last sellection?

Here is also picture, that shows my problem: http://postimg.org/image/icnw0ves3/

One more wish is, that if i choose Europe and then Germany it shows me Germany, if then i select Spain, delete Germany and write Spain. So only last selection is written. Sometimes i need both selections to be written sometimes just last one.

My boss just complicated my life and have a wish that choosen countries are written like this:

Tag1| Asia: Souther-East =>Indonesia; Europe: Germany, Spain; Africa: Maroco, Ghana Tag2| Europe: Austria

How sholud i do it?

This code is not working in firefox (when click on tree structure is written undefined instead of the name of the country), and in ie. Working fine in chrome. What should i add?

**EDIT - One more question**

First thanks for everything, for all the effort. I have one more question, how should i do it, that if i choose Europe and then Germany it shows me Germany, if then i select Spain, delete Germany and write Spain. So only last selection is written. Sometimes i need both selections to be written sometimes just last one. Picture: postimg.org/image/mfd4hmuqr My boss just complicated my life and have a wish that choosen countries are written like this: Tag1| Asia: Souther-East =>Indonesia; Europe: Germany, Spain; Africa: Maroco, Ghana Tag2| Europe: Austria How should i do it?

**END OF EDIT**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your plugins are doing and your JS code is somewhat hard to understand, but your document structure is consistent and your requirements are not too complicated, so you can actually do this without trying to mash multiple plugins together.

I used your document structure and style rules but none of your JS code (including plugins) to achieve what you need. I only added a `tree` class to both your root `ul` elements (the ones with ids `#my-tree`1 & 2) - I will explain why further on.

Basically you want to achieve the following:

- Your tab selectors ("Tag 1" and "Tag 2") match the `.container .responsive-tabs li a` selector. When they are clicked, you want show the corresponding tab panel (all the panels match the `.responsive-tabs-panel` selector) with the ID that matches the `a` element's `href` attribute. This means just getting the `href` attribute from the clicked element, removing the "#" from it, finding the tab panel with the same ID, and adding a class of `active` to that while removing it from all the other tab panels. So:

CSS:

```
.responsive-tabs-panel{
    display:none;
}
.responsive-tabs-panel.active{
    display:block;
}
```

JS:

```
var tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.container .responsive-tabs li a'),
    tabPanels = document.getElementsByClassName('responsive-tabs-panel');

for(var i=0;i<tabs.length;i++){

    tabs[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var id = this.getAttribute('href').replace("#","");

        for(var j=0;j<tabPanels.length;j++){
             if(tabPanels[j].id==id)
                 tabPanels[j].classList.add('active');
             else tabPanels[j].classList.remove('active');
        }

    },false);
}
```

- Now, within your tab panel's root `ul` elements (to both of which I gave a class of `tree`), all your options (whether it is continent or region or country) match the `.responsive-tabs-panel li` selector. When this option has more nested options, in your document structure it means that the option has a child element with a `ul` tag, which contains further options. So if the clicked option has more options, you want to give it a class of `open` and display those options, otherwise you want to give it a class of `selected`. And if an already open option is clicked again, you want to close it. So in our CSS we will want to hide all `ul` elements that have a `li` parent, unless the parent has a class of `open`.

CSS:

```
.responsive-tabs-panel .tree{
    display:block;
}
.responsive-tabs-panel li ul{
    display:none;
}
.responsive-tabs-panel li.open > ul{
    display:block;
}
```

JS:

```
var options = document.querySelectorAll('.responsive-tabs-panel li');

for(var k=0;k<options.length;k++){

    options[k].addEventListener('click',function(e){

        e.stopPropagation();
        var optionText = '',
            div = null, 
            hasMoreOptions = false;

        if(this.classList.contains('open')){
            this.classList.remove('open');
            return;
        }

        for(var l=0;l<this.children.length;l++){

            if(this.children[l].tagName.toLowerCase()=='div'){
                div = this.children[l];
                optionText = div.innerText;
            }
            else if(this.children[l].tagName.toLowerCase()=='ul'){
                hasMoreOptions = true;
            }

        }

        if(!hasMoreOptions){ 
            this.classList.add('selected');
        }
        else this.classList.add('open');

    },false);
}
```

(`e.stopPropagation` is important here, because if we don't call it, the eventListener function will also be called on every `li` element that is the parent of the clicked `li`. Stopping it means it will only be called on the actual clicked option, and not all its parents that match the selector provided when defining the `options` array.)

- As you might have noted above, we also extracted the option text from the clicked `li` element, by finding its `div` child and getting the innerText of that. This is because you want to record all the elements that the user clicks on. anytime either a tab or an option is clicked. The simplest way to do that is to create a div element with the text of the clicked option, and to append it to the `.container2 p` element in the right container.
- If you also want to show the nesting level of the selected option, then based on your document structure the simplest way to do this is to count how many parent `ul` elements it has until it reaches the `ul.tree` element (this is why I added the class to the root `ul`). You can multiply this number by 4 spaces and add it before the option text when you append it to the `.container2 p` element with couple of simple functions.

.

```
var selectedOptions = document.querySelector('.container2 p');

function getNestingLevel(li){

    var level = 1,
        parent = li.parentNode;

    while(!parent.classList.contains('tree')){
        if(parent.tagName.toLowerCase()=='ul')
            level++;
        parent = parent.parentNode;
    }

    return level;
}

function updateSelectedOptions(optionText,nestingLevel){

    var div = document.createElement('div'),
        indent = '';

    for(var i=1;i<nestingLevel*4;i++)
        indent = indent + '&nbsp;';

    div.innerHTML = indent+optionText;
    selectedOptions.appendChild(div);
}
```

Now you only need to insert one line each in your earlier eventListener functions (one for tags, and one for options) by calling `updateSelectedOptions`:

For tags:

```
updateSelectedOptions(this.innerText,0);
```

For options:

```
updateSelectedOptions(optionText,getNestingLevel(this));
```

Here is a pen combining everything: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxXZYZ

**Edited in response:**

The problem on IE & Firefox was that I was using `.innerText`, whereas I should've used the more-supported `.innerHTML` property. So that has been fixed. As for your other issue, I have also changed the code to support your requirements. Now the default tag (the `.responsive-tabs li a` open by default) has a `default` class which comes into play if the user selects an option without choosing a tab first. Also now there is a global variable called `latestOpen` which contains the latest element clicked open. Now we pass our clicked `li` element straight to the `updateSelectedOptions` function, which calculates how near the latestOpen element was, and updates the `.container2 p` with all the options in between. It also calculates the nesting and updates the `latestOpen` variable.

Comment: This answer is great. Thank you very much for all the effort. I have one more question. You can see it bellow. Thank you again.

Comment: First thanks for everything, for all the effort. I have one more question, how should i do it, that if i choose Europe and then Germany it shows me Germany, if then i select Spain, delete Germany and write Spain. So only last selection is written. Sometimes i need both selections to be written sometimes just last one. Picture: http://postimg.org/image/mfd4hmuqr/ My boss just complicated my life and have a wish that choosen countries are written like this: Tag1| Asia: Souther-East =>Indonesia; Europe: Germany, Spain; Africa: Maroco, Ghana Tag2| Europe: Austria How should i do it?